# multiple vendors have applications built into a system image / signatureOrSystem

Tags: java, android

When the definition

The " signatureOrSystem " permission is used for certain special situations where multiple vendors have applications built into a system image

what do they mean? A device has apps installed onto it but what is the difference between being in the same system image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a vendor, and you want to create a custom ROM image containing the facebook app; then you have two vendors, yourself and facebook. Because the facebook app is integrated in your rom, if the user factory resets the device then facebook is still present. If you have two system images, one with facebook and one without; then it's possible to flash the rom without - factory reset, and then **not** have facebook.